# What does .NET add to Windows/Linux processes and threads?

Tags: .net, process, mono, multithreading, descriptor

As far as I know, .NET uses Windows processes.

What extra state information & functionality does it add to information contained in Windows thread/process descriptors?

And what is different in Linux (on Mono)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know nothing "new" is added. .Net encapsulates the Windows API functions in easy to use classes. A good exemple of that simplification are the System.Security.Principal namespace classes that make it VERY easy to use ACL/DACL objects, which used to be a hell in plain API.